# C double freeing error

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, free, realloc

Some starters:

creating a dynamic array of a data structure called fractions.
    Fractions has functions for setting, printing, intiting etc.

I kept getting an error for double freeing or corruption, along with a lot of gibberish from the memory map. This is the error from the output:

**double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000001976010 *****

I get that it is being freed/deleted twice but here is the code that generates the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fraction.h"

main() {
    long long int size = 0;
    long long int capacity = 10;
    int FSize = sizeof(struct fraction);
    struct fraction* array = NULL;
    struct fraction in;
    array = (struct fraction*)malloc(FSize * capacity);
    if (array == NULL) {
        printf("MALLOC DID NOT WORK\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        if (size == capacity) {
            capacity = capacity * 2;
            struct fraction* temp = NULL;
            temp = (struct fraction*)realloc(array, FSize * capacity);
            //  free(array);
            array = temp;
            free(temp);
        }
        SetFrac(&in);
        array[size++] = in;
    }
    printf("IT MADE IT HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> \n");
    getchar();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        struct fraction t = array[i];
        PrintFrac(&t);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code that works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fraction.h"

main() {
    long long int size = 0;
    long long int capacity = 10;
    int FSize = sizeof(struct fraction);
    struct fraction* array = NULL;
    struct fraction in;
    array = (struct fraction*)malloc(FSize * capacity);
    if (array == NULL) {
        printf("MALLOC DID NOT WORK\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        if (size == capacity) {
            capacity = capacity * 2;
            struct fraction* temp = NULL;
            temp = (struct fraction*)realloc(array, FSize * capacity);
            //  free(array);
            array = temp;
            free(temp);
        }
        SetFrac(&in);
        array[size++] = in;
    }
    printf("IT MADE IT HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> \n");
    getchar();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        struct fraction t = array[i];
        PrintFrac(&t);
    }
    //    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I using the free() function wrong?

Comment: You are assigning `array = temp` then freeing `temp`. Since `array` is the same value, you have also freed, in effect, `array`. But then you proceed to use `array` after it was freed, which is bad. Why are you freeing it right after obtaining it with `realloc`?

Answer (score 1):

array and temp have the same pointer address, so when you free temp, array will be freed also

Answer (score 0):

You should only free "array" at the end. You must not free "temp", because you'll continue using the block (`array = temp` does not maintain a certain "reference count", but simply assigns a pointer).

Comment: I just tried removing free(temp). It worked without any errors. Won't there be a memory leak because the memory located at *temp is not being freed?

Comment: It should not be freed there and then, since the same block is still referenced by `array` and you are still using it through that pointer. At the end, when you are not accessing the memory anymore, it can safely be freed.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `free`, you should not dereference the freed memory, which you are doing by using `array[size++]`.

You should not `free()` on temp there, because you are using `array` later.

Your final commented out `free()` would be the only one that would be correct, although the program should run fine with out it.

Comment: So do I not free temp?

Comment: Indeed, you should not free temp. `array` is a copy of the pointer, so it points to the same memory block as `temp` (`array = temp;` does not copy the memory, only the value of the pointer, i.e. the address of the memory block). Since you are still using the memory block (through the pointer `array`), it should not be freed yet. It should be freed *after* use. In other words, you are not freeing `temp`, you are freeing the memory block to which `temp` and, later on, `array` point. You should not do that as long as you are still using it, i.e. not at the time you are doing it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to free(temp) after realloc temp,  just to free(array) the end of main. If you realloc is success，two possibilities:

1. temp == array (temp point to the same memory)
2. array is free and temp point to a new memory